# Strange regular expression behaviour for decimal numbers in java

Tags: java, regex, decimal

The following is my java code

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d*\\.?\\d*");
Matcher m = p.matcher("the numbers are -3.4 and 132");
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

But it fails to match either number. Can anyone shed some light upon this program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex matches the numbers, but also every inter-char. Use `\\d+` instead of your second `\\d*` for example.

I usually use the following regex to match numbers (already escaped for Java):

`[-+]?\\d*[.]?\\d+(?:[eE][-+]?\\d+)?`

Comment: Is this some weird java specific thing? I never would have picked that.

Comment: @VasiliSyrakis Nope, it's just that every used repetitor (`*` and `?`) allows a 0-time repetition, i.e. an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

Use this regex:

```
-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?
```